# Unable to go deep for certain barriers in a multilayered webpage to fetch data

Tags: vba, web-scraping

How to reach the last layer of a webpage starting from the first page? I tried but got stuck. Every time I run my code to go deep it crawls the same page again and again. Finally , I made it. Here is the full code.

```
Sub bjscrawler()
Const url = "http://www.bjs.com"
Dim html As New HTMLDocument, htm As New HTMLDocument
Dim topics As Object, post As Object, topic As Object, newlinks As String
Dim links As Object, link As Object, data As Object

With CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
.Open "GET", url, False
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
.send
html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
Set topics = html.getElementsByClassName("text")
    For Each post In topics
    Set topic = post.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
    newlinks = url & Split(topic.href, ":")(1)

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", newlinks, False
    .send
    htm.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set links = htm.getElementsByClassName("rightView")
    For Each link In links
    Set data = link.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0)
    x = x + 1
    Cells(x, 1) = data.innerText
    Next link
Next post
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is not very well writen. You should use a de bugger to step through the code to check it is indeed doing what you want it to do. That's what debuggers are for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code:

```
For m = 0 To mla.Length - 1
    z = mla(m).getAttribute("href")
    link = pageurl & Mid(z, InStr(z, ":") + 1)
Next m
```

`link` will only contain the *last* url of mla. All the other ones are "gone".

Also check the url you created in link, it can be invalid. As a result, the next GET wil fail, but the code doesn't check that and just "carries on". `http.responseText` will for example be `404 page not found`, the call `hmm.getElementsByClassName` will return an empty set and `For Each fla` will be an emty loop.

In the code:

```
    If cc <> "" Then
        refinedlinks = cc
    End If
    validlinks = refinedlinks

     Cells(x, 1) = validlinks
     x = x + 1
```

you fill the cell also when `cc` was empty, which generates duplicates. Change to:

```
    If cc <> "" Then
        Cells(x, 1) = cc
        x = x + 1
    End If
```

When you say

```
   ''' I'm stuck at this point. Not i can pull links from here nor can go 
   '''deeper. Because object elements are not same for all the links.
```

you probably want to process all the cells you just filled, not only this last `validlinks`. So iterate over the cells:

```
    lastx= x
    For x= 1 to lastx
        http.Open "GET", Cells(x, 1), False
```

I am not sure what you mean with "Because object elements are not same for all the links". I hope these suggestions help you.

Comment: Dear Paul Ogilvie,  

What i meant by saying "Because object elements are not same for all the links"
is that suppose i scraped some links at this point and try to inspect elements for those links then i can find that some links ended there and class element
for those links are different than those are yet to end. More specifically: some links contain
"category ng-scope" as class element and some contain "productbox". Hope i made myself clear. 
BTW, i do not want to create another subroutine either. All i wanna do is embed all the code in a single 
subroutine.This is it.